# Call custom function from dynamic added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, picturecut

i have this jQuery function:

```
        $("#agenda_image_1,#agenda_image_2,#agenda_image_3").PictureCut({
        InputOfImageDirectory       : "image",
        PluginFolderOnServer        : "../xxx/modules/xxx/assets/js/jQuery-Picture-Cut-master/",
        FolderOnServer              : "/xxx/assets/profile/",
        EnableCrop                  : true,
        CropWindowStyle             : "Bootstrap",
        ActionToSubmitCrop          : "../user/ajax/saveImgDataInSession",
        ActionToSubmitUpload        : "../user/ajax/uploadImgData",
        ImageButtonCSS              : {
            border:0,
            width :83,
            height:83
        },
        /*EnableButton : true,*/
        CropModes                   : {
            widescreen: false,
            letterbox: false,
            free   : true
        },
        EnableResize: true,
        MinimumWidthToResize: ($(window).width() / 10) * 8.5,
        MinimumHeightToResize: ($(window).height() / 10) * 7.5

    });
```

This is called by clicking on:

```
<div class="pointer agenda-nopic agendaimageplaceholder" id="agenda_image_1"></div>
```

Then this was added dynamiclly:

```
<div class="pointer agenda-nopic agendaimageplaceholder" id="agenda_image_2"></div>
```

By:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("click", "#agenda_add_image", function() {
    $("#agenda_image_1").clone().empty().insertAfter("#agenda_image_1");
    $("#agenda_image_1").attr('id', 'agenda_image_' + $(".agendaimageplaceholder").length);
});
});
```

Clicking "#agenda_image_2" the function wasn't fired.

I think i need something like this:

```
$(document).on("PictureCut", "#agenda_image_1,#agenda_image_2", function() {

};
```

**UPDATE:**
This doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("click", "#agenda_add_image", function() {
$("#agenda_image_1").clone().empty().insertAfter("#agenda_image_1");
$("#agenda_image_1").attr('id', 'agenda_image_' + $(".agendaimageplaceholder").length);

$("#agenda_image_2").PictureCut({
        InputOfImageDirectory       : "image",
        PluginFolderOnServer        : "../xx/modules/xxx/assets/js/jQuery-Picture-Cut-master/",
        FolderOnServer              : "/xxx/assets/profile/",
        EnableCrop                  : true,
        CropWindowStyle             : "Bootstrap",
        ActionToSubmitCrop          : "../user/ajax/saveImgDataInSession",
        ActionToSubmitUpload        : "../user/ajax/uploadImgData",
        ImageButtonCSS              : {
            border:0,
            width :83,
            height:83
        },
        /*EnableButton : true,*/
        CropModes                   : {
            widescreen: false,
            letterbox: false,
            free   : true
        },
        EnableResize: true,
        MinimumWidthToResize: ($(window).width() / 10) * 8.5,
        MinimumHeightToResize: ($(window).height() / 10) * 7.5

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: How do you add element dynamically?

Comment: Look at my edited question at "By:"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Delegation is for events. It appears (i could be wrong), the plugin you are using doesn't support any delegate method. So, initialize plugin inside `#agenda_add_image` click handler for new added element.

Comment: Ok look at my edit "UPDATE: This doesn't work". This way?

Comment: The click on "agenda_image_2" is now firing but no more on "agenda_image_1".
OK the FIRST element can be clicked. If "agenda_image_1" is first it will be also fired. But not "agenda_image_2" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it... not nice but works...

First init the plugin for agenda_image_1.

```
$("#agenda_image_1").PictureCut({});
```

Then after adding new elements... reinit for agenda_image_1 and then for all other added like this ...

```
$(document).on("click", "#agenda_add_image", function() {
    var nextID = "#agenda_image_2"; // for example
    $("#agenda_image_1").PictureCut({});
    $(nextID).PictureCut({});
});
```

The second init for #agenda_image_1 is necessary. Without it, it doesn't work.